# Javascript Dynamically Creating an eventListener with event and this parameters

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

1st post - go easy.

I'm trying to create an eventListener in javascript that has the same effect as
The ondrop function below:

```
<tr 
    id=rw01 
    draggable=true
    ondragstart=drag(event);
    ondrop=drop(event,this);
>some HTML</tr>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('id', ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev,r) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var oldRowID = ev.dataTransfer.getData('id');
    var newRowNo = r.rowIndex;
    var tbl = document.getElementById('main');
    newRow = tbl.insertRow(newRowNo);
    oldRow = document.getElementById(oldRowID);
    newRow.innerHTML = oldRow.innerHTML;
    newRow.id = oldRowID;
    newRow.draggable = true;
    newRow.addEventListener('dragstart',drag(event));
    newRow.addEventListener('drop', function() {
             drop(event,newRow);
        } );
    oldRowNo = oldRow.rowIndex;
    tbl.deleteRow(oldRowNo);
}
```

The error I get is when the drop function is called by the ondrop event on the newly created row. The line

```
 var oldRowID = ev.dataTransfer.getData('id')
```

returns nothing - suggesting the drag event is not passing the element id to the drop function.

All function being called from the html are working fine - the same functions being called by the newly created event handlers are not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass event argument explicitly. Instead just the below code:

```
newRow.addEventListener('dragstart',drag);
```

And the drag() function will be same as you defined.

Now the drop() function which you have defined should have only the event argument:

```
function drop(ev) {

}
```

And you can use `this` object to access the current object.

So while adding the drop event listener for newly added row use below code:

```
newRow.addEventListener('drop',drop);
```

Also use below HTML markup:

```
<tr 
    id=rw01 
    draggable=true
    ondragstart=drag();
    ondrop=drop();
>some HTML</tr>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank @ShwethaU I got the listeners to work on the inserted row. However I can't figure out how to get the id of the element that has had the dragged object dropped on it. The drop() function fires but that function needs the id of the recieving. in short which element fired the drop function in the markup I was pass 'this' to get that info. The 'function drop(ev) {' doesn't need the ev now as far as I can tell.

Comment: UPDATE. All fixed thanks heaps. I used `event.target.parentElement.id` although the `parentElement` was only necessary because I was dropping on a <TD> and I wanted the id of the parent <TR>